# How to point at incompatible pointer type in C?

Tags: c, pointers, casting

In the book [Learn C The Hard Way](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/) at excercise [15](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex15.html) there is suggestion to break program by pointing integer pointer at array of strings and using C cast to force it. How can I do it?

Comment: Why do you want to do it?

Comment: You already say how to do it (“using C case”). What is your question?

Comment: @FUZxxl I'm beginner at C so I don't know how to do it with casting types.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom There is a section in every lession at given book where you can find suggestions for breaking program and making willing compiler errors.

Comment: @Nikola Do you have an array of strings or characters?

Comment: @Ehsan Nope, array of strings. You can see that double level pointer is used at exercise (pointing to array with strings).

Comment: C compilers never give error in casts ( maybe C++ compilers give it depends on the compiler )

Comment: They don't give errors because wild pointer casts is undefined behavior, which always occurs at run-time.

Comment: @Ehsan Oh yes, they do. Try `(int*)1.0`.

Comment: bro I didn't wrote completely yes of course converting a double to pointer but in conversion of pointer types they don't give errors because pointers ( not long pointers ) are all 4 bytes.

Comment: @Ehsan I've talked about section in the book, not about giving compiler errors through casts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a small example. the result depends on the endianness of your system and the size of `int`. I would expect the first or fourth character to change to the next character in the alphabet.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    char string[100] = "Somestring";
    int *p;

    /* Let p point to the string */
    p = (int*)string;

    /* modify a value */
    (*p)++;

    /* Let's see if any character got changed */ 
    printf("%s", string);

    return 0;
}
```

It should be pointed out that not all casts are safe and that the result could be implementation defined or undefined. This example is actually undefined, since `int` could have stricter alignment constraints than `char`.

When writing portable code you need to take great care when using casts.

The code above could break on any system where `sizeof(int)` is greater than the string length regardless of alignment issues. In this case, where the string has size 100, we wouldn't expect that to happen in a long while. Had the string been 4-7 bytes it could happen sooner. The jump from 32- to 64-bit pointers broke a lot of old code that assumed that pointers and `int` were the same size.

**Edit:**

Is there an easy fix to the alignment problem? What if we could somehow make sure that the string starts in an address that is also suitable for an `int`. Fortunately, that is easy. The memory allocation function `malloc` is guaranteed to return memory aligned at an address that is suitable for any type.

So, instead of

```
char string[100] = "Somestring";
```

we can use

```
char *string = malloc(100);
strcpy(string, "Somestring");
```

The subsequent cast is now safe alignment-wise and is portable to systems where `int` is smaller than 100.

Note that `malloc` is declared in `stdlib.h`, so we should add the following at the top of our code file:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
```

Comment: That could even crash on some hardware where alignment constraints matter (not x86).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch That's the point of the exercise the OP is reading - he's just asking about the particular syntax of doing it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I've added a couple of paragraphs on the perils of casting.

Comment: Also I believe this breaks the strict aliasing rule. You can go from _type_ to character, not the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

That's simply an abusive way of casting.

```
// setup the pointers to the start of the arrays
int *cur_age = ages;
char **cur_name = names;
```

What the author of that link meant by "to break program by pointing integer pointer at array of strings and using C cast to force it." He meant that you can write something like this `int *cur_age = (int *)names;` That is to cast **a pointer to pointer to char** to **a pointer to int**. You can do that in C, which allows you to cast from one type of pointer to another type of pointer; but be warned you need to know what you are doing.

Here the author wanted to show how to break a program by pointing a pointer to a wrong type. His example, however, is probably making you more confused rather than helping you to understand pointers.

Answer (score 1):

To cast, use the cast operator: `(type)expression`. For example, to cast an expression of type `double` to `int`:

```
(int)sqrt(2);
```

In your specific case, cast `names` to `int*` (the type of `cur_age`) to break the program:

```
cur_age = (int*)names;
```

Answer (score -1):

To point incompatible pointer in c you only need to cast it to void.

```
//array of string declaration
char aStr[50][50];
Int *pint;

//do whatever you need with string array

pint = (*int)(*void)aStr;
```

I'm writing this from my cell phone.

if you increment your pointer past the allocated memory, you might end up in your program stack and change value to it.

Comment: This would violate [strict aliasing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule).